# phonegap permissions not being asked when installing apk

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

This is my config.xml for phonegap with JQM

but when i install the APK after compiling with adobe build it asks me only for GPS & Audio recording. Not for camera etc. then the camera function is not available to my APP of course. any ideas?

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" />    
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" /> 
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" />   
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" />    
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" />  
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />

    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" /> 
    <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true"/>

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>

    <icon src="icon.png" />

    <access origin="*" />


    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include **source="npm"** at the end of your tags like so:

```
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm"/>
```

J